# Executing sub query with case

Tags: sql-server

I have to run a sub query with case statement inside of sub query. When I run the sub query independently it works, but as a sub query it gives following error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

This is my query :

```
select categoryid, categoryname, (select (case when c.ParentCategoryId is NULL then null else c.CategoryName end) as Parent_Category_Name from Categories c) from Categories
```

My categories table has 3 columns : CategoryId, CategoryName, ParentCategoryId

I am not able to figure out how can I fetch required result.

Comment: where are you running the query ? in php or java or someplace else ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subquery

```
(select (case when c.ParentCategoryId is NULL then null else c.CategoryName end) as Parent_Category_Name 
from Categories c)
```

will be return all categories, it causes problem.
As my understand, your query should be:

```
select c.categoryid, c.categoryname, 
CASE 
     when c.ParentCategoryId IS NULL then '' 
     ELSE pr.categoryname
END as Parent_Category_Name
from Categories c
LEFT JOIN Categories pr ON c.ParentCategoryId = pr.categoryid
```

Comment: getting error of incorrect syntax. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
and Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: I don't see any error syntax. Check your column name, table name

Comment: Which version of SQL you are using? IIF is avaiable from 2012 ++

Comment: sql server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is what you need to do to your query:

```
select 
    C1.categoryid, 
    C1.categoryname,
    case 
        when c1.ParentCategoryId is NULL 
        then null 
        else c2.CategoryName 
    end as Parent_Category_Name 
from Categories C1 
left join Categories C2
on C1.ParentCategoryID=C2.CategoryID
```

your subquery works and helps you find `parent_category_name` for all categories.
you don't need to repeat the whole thing for integrating this logic in other query; simply the select part if sufficient.

**More simply you do not need a case evaluation with JOIN.**

```
select 
    C1.categoryid, 
    C1.categoryname,
    c2.CategoryName as Parent_Category_Name 
from Categories C1 
left join Categories C2
on C1.ParentCategoryID=C2.CategoryID
```

Comment: your query worked for me. that was very silly of me I didn't noticed that. Don't know the reason of downvote.

Comment: @AmitKaushal See my update; Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

Specify Top(1) in your sub query. It seems it return more than one value which not accepted as sub query result.

```
select categoryid, categoryname, (select TOP(1) (case when c.ParentCategoryId is NULL then null else c.CategoryName end) as Parent_Category_Name from Categories c) from Categories
```

Comment: can I know reason for the downVote?

Comment: your query does not produce required result. it gives me null in all rows of 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select categoryid, categoryname, case when c.ParentCategoryId is NULL then null else c.CategoryName end as Parent_Category_Name from Categories
```

Comment: It would be helpful if the one who down voted my answer can explain the reason? I can rectify the mistake that I have done here.

Comment: Even I believe you are correct(see my answer); someone is on downvoting spree, so I guess same person downvoted both of us.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Yes. Probably we should delete our answers it seems. getting down votes without a reason.

Comment: That would be the easy way out; we must rather learn and correct ourselves. That's the way forward